# Definite or indefinite adjectives with possessive personal determiners in Germanic?

Tags: germanic-languages, adjectives, german

While both German and Danish have different forms of adjectives in definite and indefinite noun phrases, noun phrases with possessive personal determiners pattern with the indefinite noun phrases in German,

> Ein guter Mann - a good man
>   Mein guter Mann - my good man
>   Der gute Mann - the good man

while they pattern with definite noun phrases in Danish (and presumably Norwegian and Swedish):

> En god mand - a good man
>   Min gode mand - my good man
>   Den gode mand - the good man

This seems like a curious fact, since AFAIK the words are pairwise cognates. Is there a logical explanation?

Comment: It's dainichi's prerogative to simply pair possessive personal determiners with in/definite NPs. If, though, dainichi had paired negative articles with in/definitive NPs, then full parallelism would obtain: _en/ingen god mand_ vs _ein/kein guter Mann_. So what makes dainichi's choice relevant?

Comment: @dainichi I don't know if this can help. But in German, possessives are called "ein-words", as they inflect (and sound) like indefinite articles. So maybe the reason of the discrepancy for possessive, despite their determinative quality, is simply analogy of sound with the indefinite articles.

Comment: @ThomasGross OP's question is legit. He is asking why in Scandinavian languages adjectives after possessives decline strongly, and in German weakly. Your point that with negative quantifiers the languages do the same makes OP's point even more interesting.

Comment: @geodude, yes, what you say kind of coincides with my own theory as well. The weak/strong adjective choice in German seems to have some kind of dependency on form (there's a pseudo-requirement that either the determiner or the adjective should carry a marker of case), whereas in Danish, it might have come to solely be based on semantics, i.e. definiteness. Just curious if anything is known about the history of this split.

Answer (score 1):

> This seems like a curious fact, since AFAIK the words are pairwise cognates. Is there a logical explanation?

The words are definitely cognates, but you have picked two languages with very different adjectival morphology, so it's not so curious that the adjectival suffixes are not the same.

The logical explanation is that all of your German examples explicitly mark the noun phrase as being masculine, nominative, singular. But your Danish examples don't mark any of those (because noun phrases are not marked for case in Danish; Danish is just like modern Dutch, or English, in this regard). But also, German adjective endings mark definiteness as well, which the Danish adjectives also don't do.

But Danish adjectives mark for [specificity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specificity_(linguistics)), which the German adjectives don't do.

So which categories are marked on Danish and German adjectives in the masculine singular:

| Category | Danish/Norwegian | German |
| --- | --- | --- |
| specificity | Marked | Unmarked |
| definiteness | Unmarked | Marked |
| case | Unmarked | Marked |

Consider these examples, (some are the same as yours, but I added vocative and put them in Norwegian since I know it better than Danish, plus I added some sentences)

- en ung mann
- min unge mann
- unge mann (this one's vocative)
- den unge mannen
- den unge mannen kommer hit imorgen
- Ser du den unge mannen i vinduet?
- Imorges kom det en ung mann med en pakke til deg
- Jeg skriver et brev til en ung mann som jeg kjenner fra krigen

As you can see, the adjectives don't mark for case as governed by a verb or preposition (the subjects and objects have the same adjective endings) and they don't mark for definiteness (the vocative noun phrase is marked the same way as the definite noun phrase). But they do mark for specificity (a feature implied both by definite and vocative).

So the reason the German and Danish paradigms don't match, is the simple reason that adjectives do not mark the same categories.

Old East Norse had adjectives marking case in the same ways as German does. But clearly, its descendant Danish has eschewed case marking, since it has a somewhat more analytical typology than either of Old East Norse or German.

Comment: I don’t really see why case morphology would make much of a difference here. Icelandic is quite similar to German in terms of case morphology (same cases morphologically marked in relatively comparable ways on comparable words), but also pairs possessive pronouns with definiteness (and I’m fairly confident the same was true of Old East Norse). It’s not really about the adjectival suffixes being different, but rather their _categories_ being different. Typologically, possessives tend to entail definiteness, so German is really the odd one out here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I am using "case morphology" here to mean something like "morphological material occupying the locus where you'd expect Indo-European case marking to happen", as the German examples indeed does, and Icelandic as you say, but I don't mean to imply that Danish has case-marking. Quite the opposite: my answer explcitely says "because nouns are not marked for case in Danish". Maybe that should read "noun-phrases".

Comment: No, I didn’t think you were saying Danish has cases; Danish and German are indeed different in this aspect. I just don’t see how or why the presence or absence of (morphological) case should affect whether or not possessive constructions are treated as definite, which seems to be what you’re arguing here. In fact, having reread it several times now, I don’t understand what you’re proposing is the actual reason for the difference at all – it seems like you’re answering an entirely different question, though I’m not sure exactly which one.

Comment: @Janus, My answer to this question is, that the German adjective endings mark case and definiteness and do not mark specificity, but the Danish and Norwegian adjective endings mark specificity only, and not definiteness nor case. None of these languages treat possessive constructions as definite. Is it confusing?

Comment: Ah, I see I did not explicitely point out that the *-e* suffix marks specificity and not definiteness. It's possible OP believes that *-e* means it's definite. Is this what your point of confusion is?

Comment: I hope I made it a bit clearer

Comment: That is indeed much clearer! I’ve not seen the claim that the weak form in Scandinavian denotes specificity and not definiteness before (but then I’ve not really seen specificity much at all). Going by the Wikipedia article you link to, definiteness and specificity are independent enough that you can generate NPs that are definite but non-specific, or indefinite but specific – but in all the examples given, the adjective in Scandinavian would follow the definiteness, not the specificity. Do you have a source that fleshes out the argument more?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What do you mean? There are no Danish or Norwegian examples on the page I linked. Specificity in these languages is a feature implied by definiteness or vocative, and is distinct from semantic specificity in an analogous manner to the distinction between grammatical gender and biological sex, but none of this is discussed on the Wikipedia. I'll see if I can find a page that discusses this.

Comment: Can you read Norwegian? [this page](https://snl.no/definitthet) calls it definitthet, but what it's actually talking about seems confused between definiteness and specificity, and also doesn't mention vocatives

Comment: That SNL article seems to align fairly well with Wikipedia’s description, describing specificity as a semantic category that generally, but not always, aligns with definiteness. It also says that in cases where the head noun is unmarked for definiteness, specificity can be marked by the **definite** form of the adjective, so they too consider the weak forms to denote definiteness rather than specificity; weak forms are also given in the article on definiteness, not the one on specificity. (It does briefly mention vocatives, incidentally, by using _lille venn_ as an example.)

Comment: As for Danish, I’ve just looked in Hansen & Heltoft, _Grammatik over det danske sprog_ (2011), and they explicitly say in _II §7.2, anm. 2_ (vol. 1, pp. 178–9) that Danish has no grammaticalised equivalent: “Når disse varianter [= specific and non-specific] her nævnes på anmærkningsniveau, er det fordi forskellen ikke er grammatikaliseret. Der er ingen bøjningsformer der markerer denne forskel.” However, they define defineteness as entailing _identifiability_ and only consider specificity to be a property of indefinite forms (not sure why), so it’s not fully comparable.

Comment: Also, on the topic of vocatives, note that in German, _singular_ vocatives always take the strong form of adjectives, whereas _plural_ vocatives can take either weak or strong forms.